# Remove specific hash from URL on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I've a bit of a problem. I'm using remodal which uses hashes in the URL to display a modal. In my case it's `http://www.test.com/#my-remodal`. When the modal is now open and I reload the page, the hash is still there and the modal opens after the reload which is not good in my case.

So is there any option to remove the hash when the user reloads the page when the modal is open?

This is my code:

```
jQuery( window ).load( function () {
    if ( window.location.hash.indexOf( "#my-remodal" ) > -1 ) {
        window.location.hash = "";
    }
} );
```

Comment: You could add an event listener for either load or unload of the window, that simply `window.location.hash = ''`

Comment: But I need to be careful I found out trying this because there are also hashes used for tabbing. In this case the tab selection hashes are not working anymore. So do you think it works to check if it's a specific hash within the load listener?

Comment: You could check for the hash to be my-remodal before removing it, sure

Comment: @Taplar So I figured it out - a bit. See my code above. It's removing it only after the first reload but in this case the hash is still there.